# Microsoft Azure Storage Tool - AzCopy:batch command for scheduling

Tags: azure

How can we create batch command for AzCopy. as I want to schedule this command. Please guide me how can I schedule this command. Currently I am manually running this command in 'Microsoft Azure Storage Tool' and want to automate.

Comment: hi there Ahwani, what's you goal/ what do you want ot achieve?

Comment: I am moving file from one Azure server to another Azure server, for this we are running AzCopy command in Microsoft Azure Storage Tool on every week of saturday. So, I want to schedule this command as a job with automatic execution on every week of Saurday. Thanks

Comment: dear Ashwani, I would advise you to use Azure Automation instead.. take a look at this template script https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Copy-a-File-to-an-Azure-VM-d2ad9e1f and start from there :-) Besides AZCopy is tehre for moving files to blobstorage and not between VM's :-) (that you could do with a simple xcopy (if machines are in a VNet) or use Azure Files as a File share and always put your files there (no copy needed then :-) )

Answer (score 1):

Schedule a PowerShell job to run azcopy.exe. See [PowerShell scheduled jobs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/05/12/introduction-to-powershell-scheduled-jobs.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge PS script containing azure powershell cmdlets cannot be scheduled by windows task scheduler. Probably it lacks something which cannot establish a connection to execute azure ps cmdlets through that script.

**NOTE:**
Even if you schedule it it will execute the script, it will show status as completed; but it wont actually do its job.

I would recommend you to better go for azure runbooks for this task. Also you can use `copyAzureStorageBlob` cmdlet for the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use Windows Task Scheduler to start powershell script which starts your batch file.

Powershell script contains only one line e.g.:
Start-Process C:\foobar\azcopy.bat